# Getting rid of lateinit when converting Spring Java8 Junit test to Kotlin

Tags: java, spring, junit, kotlin

I'm busy converting Java8 Junit tests to Kotlin

Java8:

```
@ActiveProfiles("junit")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml"})
public class AuctionTest {

    @Autowired
    AccountProcessor ap;

    @Test
    @Rollback
    public void securityTest(){
```

Rewriting it in Kotlin, it looks like this:

```
@ActiveProfiles("junit")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml")
class AccountTest() {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var ap: AccountProcessor

    @Test
    @Rollback
    fun securityTest() {
```

The above unit test runs fine, but I want to get rid of the `lateinit`

Rewriting it like this:

```
@ActiveProfiles("junit")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml")
class AccountTest(@Autowired val ap: AccountProcessor) {

    @Test
    @Rollback
    fun securityTest() {
```

And Junit complains

> java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public
>   zero-argument constructor
>
> at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:104)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:31)
>     at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:96)
>     at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

Is there a way around this or am I stuck with `lateinit` `@Autowire`s ?

Comment: 1. There's nothing wrong with having properties as `lateinit`. The reason why `lateinit` keyword was created, is to handle such cases. I don't see any reasons why you'd want to get rid of lateinit. 2. As the exception message reads, you need to have a no-arg constructor, so it's impossible to have @Autowired constructor args.

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible without some tinkering in Junit. If you do want to go that road, you'll need to build your own [Runner](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/Runner.html) that initialises spring and then instantiates the test class by calling the constructor. Take a look at the [Parameterized](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html) to see how to instantiate a test class that requires parameters.

Comment: Fair enough, seems like the easiest route is to just leave `lateinit` in there for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of spring component to inject processor you should annotate constructor, not constructor argument:

```
@Service
class AccountTest @Autowired constructor(val ap: AccountProcessor) {
}
```

Bit Junit adds their restrictions on how test classes should be implemented, and it's not possible to inject bean way you want.

ps. From Spring 4.3 you no need `@Autowired`:

```
@Service
class AccountTest(val ap: AccountProcessor) {
```

Comment: Yes, the `@Autowired constructor` is the correct way to do it, thanks for correcting me. Pity I can't use it in unit tests, it looks so much cleaner than listing a bunch of @Autowired resources.